# How to call a table view function from within @IBAction

Tags: uitableview, swift

From within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
```

I am creating a `UITableViewCell` subclass, `PeopleTableViewCell`:

```
let cell:PeopleTableViewCell  = self.tv_main.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("row_cell") as PeopleTableViewCell
```

and then I pass some parameters

```
cell.loadItem( param1 as NSString, p2: param2 )
```

Now, in each row I have a button, and when I click it

```
@IBAction func button_clicked( param1: NSString){
```

I need to call a function in the parent table that takes as an argument one of the parameters I had passed (ex param1).

How can I accomplish this?

---

Edit, after the answer that @rob gave:

What finally worked is to

A. Pass a reference to the the parent UIViewController to the cell.loadItem

```
func cell.loadItem( param1 as NSString, controller: self )
```

and assign the controller variable to a local variable , say pvcontroller

```
 func loadItem(param1: String, controller: PeopleViewController)  {
        self.pvcontroller = controller
}
```

B. From within the PeopleTableViewCell class, from within the button click function, I call the function of the parent UIViewController via the pvcontroller variable

```
  @IBAction func person_image_click(sender: UIButton) {
       self.pvcontroller?.person_clicked(self.param1)
    }
```

Comment: BTW, make sure that `pvcontroller` is `weak`, or else you can end up with a strong reference cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Have a property in `PeopleTableViewCell` that is updated by `loadItem`:

   ```
   class PeopleTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

       var param1: NSString?

       func loadItem(param1: NSString, param2: NSString) {
           self.param1 = param1

           // do your other stuff here
       }

       // the rest of your implementation here
   }
   ```
2. Have your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call `loadItem`:

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("row_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PeopleTableViewCell

       let param1 = ...
       let param2 = ...

       cell.loadItem(param1, param2: param2)

       return cell
   }
   ```
3. Then your `@IBAction` could determine the `PeopleTableViewCell` instance, and access its property. Note, the `@IBAction` parameter, `sender`, references the button, like always. Thus, if this `@IBAction` was implemented in the table view controller, then you'd have to navigate up the view hierarchy to get to the cell, and then access the property from there:

   ```
   @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
       let cell = sender.superview?.superview as PeopleTableViewCell

       let param1 = cell.param1

       // do something with param1 now
   }
   ```

   In this example, I have the button on the cell's content view, so I'm going up two levels of `superview` (one to get the content view, one to get the cell). Just ensure that whatever you do here mirrors the hierarchy you've configured in IB.

   Alternatively, you can implement your `@IBAction` from within the `PeopleTableViewCell` class, in which case you don't have use this `sender.superview?.superview` syntax, but rather can just reference `self` to get to that `param1` property. It's up to you.